# Variable as function parameter?

Tags: c#, variables, parameters

I am doing a sort of little rpg(role playing game), in the conversations there are decisions that influence certain variables of the player. I was wondering if you knew a more effective way than mine:

```
public string Name, Nickname;
public int Age;

public void Decision(string Var, string Input)
{
    if (Var == "Name")
        Name = Input;
    else if (Var == "Nickname")
        Nickname = Input;
    else if (Var == "Age")
        Age = Convert.ToInt32(Input);
}
```

As you can see, it is pretty long for only 3 variables, but there are more... Is there a way to do it faster? Something like this:

```
public void Decision(Variable Var, string Input)
{
    Player.Var = input;
}
```

Edit: I will use a mix of the two answers:

```
    public string Nom, Prenom;
    public int Age;

    public void Decision(InfoType type, string Input)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case InfoType.Name:
                Nom = Input;
                break;
            case InfoType.Prenom:
                Prenom = Input;
                break;
        }
    }
    public void Decision(InfoType type, int Input)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case InfoType.Age:
                Age = Convert.ToInt32(Input);
                break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: `int Age` is never `== string Var` try use this instead `if(Age == Convert.ToInt32(Var) { Age = Convert.ToInt32(Input); }`

Comment: Why not assign directly to the variable you want to influence?  Presumably if you are capable of passing in a value for "Var", you know which variable you wish to change.

Comment: Honestly this seems like a design issue.  Why are you attempting to dynamically set these fields?

Comment: If you simply wanted to clean up the code a bit, you could just use a `switch` statement to break up your individual cases. A Dictionary-based approach could potentially work as well (i.e. `Properties[Var] = value`), but in this scenario, you might be better off simply setting each of them individually instead of using a single function, especially since their types can differ (i.e. ints and strings).

Comment: Because I would like to put the decisions in XNA files.

Answer (score 0):

You could make things a little bit more concise with a switch statement and also use an enum for type safety. e.g.

```
public enum InfoType {
    Name,
    Nickname,
    Age
}

public void Decision(InfoType type, string input)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case InfoType.Name:
            Name = input;
            break;
        case InfoType.NickName:
            NickName = input;
            break;
    }
}
```

And so on.

Comment: Yep, I think I will do this.

Answer (score 0):

How about method overloading?

```
public void Decision(string Var, string Input)
{
    if (Var == "Name")
        Name = Input;
    else if (Var == "Nickname")
        Nickname = Input;
}

public void Decision(int Input)
{
    Age = input
}
```

Comment: Ian's example of leveraging an enum and a case statement is also highly recommended for type safety

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use reflection. The downside to this is you will have to do additional checks for complex types, but for simple objects it can work like this.

```
public class MyObject {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class TestReflection {
    public void Test() {
        var obj = new MyObject();

        UpdateObject(obj, "Name", "THis is a name");
        UpdateObject(obj, "Age", 99);
        UpdateObject(obj, "Nickname", "This is a nickname");

        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", obj.Name, obj.Age, obj.Nickname);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private void UpdateObject(MyObject obj, string varName, object varValue) {
        //Get Properties of the object
        var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
        //Search for the property via the name passed over to the method.
        var prop = properties.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Name.Equals(varName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        //Check prop exists and set to the object.
        if(prop != null) {
            prop.SetValue(obj, varValue);
        }
    }
}
```